# Chart.js line chart does not render data lines on iOS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When creating a Chart.js line chart everything works as expected on desktop. But when viewed on iOS (iPad, iPhone, etc) the data lines are not shown on the line chart.

See live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/9pcuvthy/. It is using the bundled 2.9.3 version of Chart.js.

You can view it on iOS or using https://www.browserstack.com/ to see the problem in action. This behaviour is happening on all iOS mobile browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari).

How do I make the lines show on iOS?

```js
/* Build the chart arrays */
var lineDataPaid = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
var lineDataSEO = [0, 2, 5, 8, 12, 19, 31, 47, 67, 100];

/* Build the chart */
var ctx = document.getElementById("ROIchart").getContext("2d");
var monthLabels = [];
var dateObj = new Date();
dateObj.setDate(1);
var dateYear = dateObj.getFullYear();
var monthYearArray = [];
monthYearArray[0] = "January";
monthYearArray[1] = "February";
monthYearArray[2] = "March";
monthYearArray[3] = "April";
monthYearArray[4] = "May";
monthYearArray[5] = "June";
monthYearArray[6] = "July";
monthYearArray[7] = "August";
monthYearArray[8] = "September";
monthYearArray[9] = "October";
monthYearArray[10] = "November";
monthYearArray[11] = "December";
var dateYearLoop = dateYear;
for (i = 0; i < lineDataSEO.length; i++) {
  if (dateObj.getMonth() == 11) {
    monthLabels[i] = monthYearArray[dateObj.getMonth()] + " " + dateYearLoop;
    dateYearLoop = dateYearLoop + 1;
  dateObj.setMonth(dateObj.getMonth() + 1);
  } else {
    monthLabels[i] = monthYearArray[dateObj.getMonth()] + " " + dateYearLoop;
    dateObj.setMonth(dateObj.getMonth() + 1);
  }
}

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
 // The type of chart we want to create
 type: "line",
 // The data for our dataset
 data: {
  labels: monthLabels,
  datasets: [{
   label: "Paid Leads / Traffic",
   backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 98, 132, 0.5)",
   borderColor: "rgb(255, 98, 132)",
   data: lineDataPaid,
   fill: false,
  }, {
   label: "SEO and Content",
   backgroundColor: "rgba(46, 57, 191, 0.5)",
   borderColor: "rgb(46, 57, 191)",
   data: lineDataSEO,
   fill: true,
  }]
 },
 // Configuration options go here
 options: {
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
               var text = tooltipItems.datasetIndex === 0 ? ' paid leads for $500' : ' SEO leads for $500';
                return tooltipItems.yLabel + text;
            }
        }
    },
  legend: {
   labels: {
    fontSize: 14
   }
  },
  responsive: true,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    //maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
   xAxes: [{
    display: true,
    scaleLabel: {
     display: true,
     labelString: 'Time',
     fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     fontColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 31)',
     fontSize: '14'
    },
    ticks: {
     fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     fontColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 31)',
     fontSize: '14'
    },
    type: "time",
    time: {
     unit: "month",
     displayFormats: {
      month: 'MMM YYYY'
     }
    }
   }],
   yAxes: [{
    display: true,
    scaleLabel: {
     display: true,
     labelString: 'Leads',
     fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     fontColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 31)',
     fontSize: '14'
    },
    ticks: {
     beginAtZero: true,
     max: 100,
     fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     fontColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 31)',
     fontSize: '14'
    }
   }]
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="ROIchart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, thanks to a warning SO showed in the code examaple.

The problem is that the dates I was passing in were not in ISO standard format, and therefore moments() was defaulting to the standard date() which does not work on all browsers.

I changed around the format and it now works fine.

```js
/* Build the chart arrays */
var lineDataPaid = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
var lineDataSEO = [0, 2, 5, 8, 12, 19, 31, 47, 67, 100];

/* Build the chart */
var ctx = document.getElementById("ROIchart").getContext("2d");
var monthLabels = [];
var dateObj = new Date();
dateObj.setDate(1);
var dateYear = dateObj.getFullYear();
var monthYearArray = [];
monthYearArray[0] = "01";
monthYearArray[1] = "02";
monthYearArray[2] = "03";
monthYearArray[3] = "04";
monthYearArray[4] = "05";
monthYearArray[5] = "06";
monthYearArray[6] = "07";
monthYearArray[7] = "08";
monthYearArray[8] = "09";
monthYearArray[9] = "10";
monthYearArray[10] = "11";
monthYearArray[11] = "12";
var dateYearLoop = dateYear;
for (i = 0; i < lineDataSEO.length; i++) {
  if (dateObj.getMonth() == 11) {
    monthLabels[i] = dateYearLoop + "-" + monthYearArray[dateObj.getMonth()];
    dateYearLoop = dateYearLoop + 1;
  dateObj.setMonth(dateObj.getMonth() + 1);
  } else {
    monthLabels[i] = dateYearLoop + "-" + monthYearArray[dateObj.getMonth()];
    dateObj.setMonth(dateObj.getMonth() + 1);
  }
}

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
 // The type of chart we want to create
 type: "line",
 // The data for our dataset
 data: {
  labels: monthLabels,
  datasets: [{
   label: "Paid Leads / Traffic",
   backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 98, 132, 0.5)",
   borderColor: "rgb(255, 98, 132)",
   data: lineDataPaid,
   fill: false,
  }, {
   label: "SEO and Content",
   backgroundColor: "rgba(46, 57, 191, 0.5)",
   borderColor: "rgb(46, 57, 191)",
   data: lineDataSEO,
   fill: true,
  }]
 },
 // Configuration options go here
 options: {
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
               var text = tooltipItems.datasetIndex === 0 ? ' paid leads for $500' : ' SEO leads for $500';
                return tooltipItems.yLabel + text;
            }
        }
    },
  legend: {
   labels: {
    fontSize: 14
   }
  },
  responsive: true,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    //maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
   xAxes: [{
    display: true,
    scaleLabel: {
     display: true,
     labelString: 'Time',
     fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     fontColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 31)',
     fontSize: '14'
    },
    ticks: {
     fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     fontColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 31)',
     fontSize: '14'
    },
    type: "time",
    time: {
     unit: "month",
     displayFormats: {
      month: 'MMM YYYY'
     }
    }
   }],
   yAxes: [{
    display: true,
    scaleLabel: {
     display: true,
     labelString: 'Leads',
     fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     fontColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 31)',
     fontSize: '14'
    },
    ticks: {
     beginAtZero: true,
     max: 100,
     fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
     fontColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 31)',
     fontSize: '14'
    }
   }]
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="ROIchart"></canvas>
</div>
```